# Calling method set as target on UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, methods, uibutton, target

If I have a UIButton which has a target set, is there a way to call this method without explicitly calling it?

For example:

```
[newViewController.button addTarget:self action:@selector(MyMethod) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I'm then looking to call this method in `newViewController` but cannot as `MyMethod` belongs to the parent view. So I really want to be able to say, just call the method/target on the UIButton button. But how can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just found out how to do this. Was pretty easy, feel like a noob asking now!

```
[button sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```